# Rock Paper Scissors with winner or loser result

Tags: python

I just started to learn Python and tried to make this game by myself for self-training.

I have made the game taking 2 more hours.
But I'd like to make score result(either 3 win or 3 lose) with break.

I don't know how to use while statement with break on this situation.
Hope to help me please.

```
import random

user_choice = input("select one of rock, paper, scissors. ")

Rock_paper_scissors = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
computer_choice = Rock_paper_scissors[random.randint(0,2)]

if user_choice == computer_choice:
    print("Draw.")

elif user_choice == "rock":
    if computer_choice == "paper":
        computer_score += 1
        print("lose.")
    else:
        user_score += 1
        print("win.")

elif user_choice == "scissors":
    if computer_choice == "rock":
        computer_score += 1
        print("lose.")
    else:
        user_score += 1
        print("win.")

elif user_choice == "paper":
    if computer_choice == "scissors":
        computer_score += 1
        print("lose")
    else:
        user_score += 1
        print("win")
```

Comment: You need to show that you've tried writing some code or done some research - i.e. the `while` loop (which is one way of doing it). Simply saying "I don't know how to use _x_" won't get you much in the way of help

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop in python works like this:

```
while condition:
    do something...
```

While the condition is `true` the loop will keep going, in this case you don't need a `break` statement, you could simply do:

```
user_score = 0
computer_score = 0
while (user_score < 3 and computer_score < 3):
    game...
```

If you really want to use a `break` statement, you could do it like this:

```
user_score = 0
computer_score = 0
while True:
    if (user_score >= 3 or computer_score >= 3):
        break
    game...
```

That way the loop will keep going forever, since the condition is `True`, but the `if` inside the loop will call a `break` when a player scores 3 points.

`user_score` and `computer_score` are initialized to zero, you always have to initialize your variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop your procedure for 3 times, stop when one of 2 opponent reach score of 2.
It will look something like this

```
while (user_score < 3 and computer_score < 3):
     <continue playing>
```

If you want to use break:

```
while True:
     <continue playing>
     if user_score == 3 or computer score == 3:
          break
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Well first youll want to add those score variables at the begging of your code.

```
computer_score=0
user_score=0
```

then you want to have a while statement that also encloses the user input

```
Rock_paper_scissors = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

while True:

    user_choice = input("select one of "rock, paper, scissors. ")

    computer_choice = Rock_paper_scissors[random.randint(0,2)]

    #Your if/elif statements go here
```

And at the end and an if statement to check if someone has a score of 3 or more

```
    if user_score >= 3:
        print('You win')
        break
```